# Open Jpg in morzila firefox using jsp link dynamicaly generated for image

Tags: html

How to open jpeg in jsp file using Mozila Firefox? It works in IE but can't run in Firefox by passing it's `scr` tag dynamicaly

It will say `E:\stxavier\docs\7.jpg`

```
e not protocol error
```

and without generate dynamic content it will see path like

```
e|\stxavier\docs\7.jpg
```

So I can't understand that meaning I also use this thing but my other link to pdf or avi file is lost

Comment: Possibly add Content-Type/MIME Type to response output.

Comment: What do you mean by "open" exactly? Link to it? Pass it through?

Answer (score 1):

To link to a local file, like "E:\stxavier\docs\7.jpg" you should prepend the local path with "file:///".("file:///e:/stxavier/docs/7.jpg")
But even if you do this Firefox and Opera sometimes DO NOT ALLOW links to the local file system.
Sometimes it will work sometimes it will not, you just can not relly on links to local files.